# How do I give tasks a priority relative to other tasks

Tags: 2013, tasks

I have a list of tasks that should be completed in priority order. I want the ability for someone to add a task to the list and be able to place it anywhere in the order, for example, they could add a task and make it have the least priority to be completed or make it the highest priority to be completed or somewhere in between.

Is there any way to do this in SharePoint? By the way, I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an out of the box priority on task items, but that doesn't seem like it's enough for what you're trying to do. Nor does the Predecessor column quite get you there.

In other situations, I use a SortOrder column for items in a list. I give the user the capability to drag and drop the items into relative positions and write the changes back to the sort order column. You could do something similar here.  All with script, of course!

Comment: I've been able to implement the order column and a function that swaps the order of two items, how do you go about the drag and drop aspect of this?

Comment: I use jQueryUI's .sortable() function (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), often in tandem with a DVWP to lay down the initial data.

Comment: Finally implemented a fully working solution today, even got it working with grouping :D

Answer (score 0):

Task columns in SharePoint do not have any activities (or business logic) attached to them, therefore Priority simply represents a value and nothing more.

Alternatives would be to create a view ordering based on these priorities and simply allow user to set priority in the standard way, whereas the view will show them appropriately.

Also, you could rely on using JSOM (JavaScript Object Model) to or event handlers (heavier code development) to implement some other logic. See an example quite cool by Eric  http://www.screenr.com/36Y or http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.ch/2009/03/sharepoint-past-due-late-tasks-in-task.html